# Save the values of radio button on change into database using jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have my markup like this. Here you can see I have a form and inside that I have two radio buttons. In the form i don't have any submit button. I want to save the values of radio buttons on change into database. I mean to say when I will select any radio button then its value will be saved into database in ajax.

```
<form action="">
<div class="radio show-options">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="active" id="show_popup" value="1">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio show-options">
 <label>
    <input type="radio" name="active" id="show_slider" value="0" checked="checked">
 </label>
</div>
</form>
```

For me I have the database like this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `slide_options` (
  `options_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `options_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`options_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

In jQuery I have this piece of code so far.

```
jQuery('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function() {
    var SelectedValue = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    console.log(SelectedValue);
  });
});
```

So can someone kindly tell me how to save the values to database using ajax? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: have you tried searching for it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="">
<div class="radio show-options">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="active" id="show_popup" value="1" onclick="save_val('1')">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio show-options">
 <label>
    <input type="radio" name="active" id="show_slider" value="0" checked="checked" onclick="save_val('0')">
 </label>
</div>
</form>

function save_val(va) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "save_val.php?option="+va,
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
    }).done(function(respond){

    });
}
```

save_val.php file

create connection to database and then apply insert query like this :

```
mysql_query("insert into slide_options set options_type = '".$_GET['option']."'");
```